# How to use Composer installed classes via autoload.php?

Tags: php, composer-php

You may find this question a bit odd, but I read couple of articles and it is still unclear for me how to make it work. I have a server with composer installed I made it to request DomCrawler via request command, it installed it successfully, I have vendor\symfony directory and file autoload.php, which I include to my script. It returns object of Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader which seems to have classes

```
[prefixLengthsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
    (
        [S] => Array
            (
                [Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\] => 26
                [Symfony\Polyfill\Ctype\] => 23
                [Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\] => 29
            )

    )
```

How to use them now? In manuals they are usually registered to that moment and people can simply make variable such as `$var = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler();` in my case it seems some additional command it required to include that classes to code, and it is unclear for me which one I have to use? Or how to include these classes to my code and to work with them...

```
$loader = require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';

$classes = get_declared_classes();

if( class_exists( 'Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' ) ){
    $methods = get_class_methods( 'Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' );
}

echo '<pre>';
//print_r($loader);
print_r( $classes );
//print_r( $methods );
echo '</pre>';

die();
```

I don't see and crawler/symphony classes. Only composer classes are added to classes which php brings.

Comment: See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: Of cause I have seen it already. That is why I ask for help. I include $loader = require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php'; file successfully and it only returns Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader

Comment: Like it says, *Including that file will also return the autoloader instance, so you can store the return value of the include call in a variable and add more namespaces. This can be useful for autoloading classes in a test suite, for example.*. If this doesn't apply to you then you can ignore the return value, and just require the file.

Comment: If you think that it is not working for you, you should show how it does not working. Which classes are not loaded? How do you use it and what is your project structure?

Comment: If it's specifically that `DomCrawler` isn't loading, it's probably because the class is called `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler`.

Comment: Oops sorry, in examples which I have seen people installed packages added autoload.php which have already included their classes. If I need Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\ I have to include it manually via additional include

Comment: I symply need Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\ outside Symphony, which I don't use, I thought it would be easier to use Composer to download all packages and dependencies. So I could simply include Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\ to my project

Comment: Remove the `$loader = ` part. You just need `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php;` and should be able to call any of the classes which you installed via composer require.

Comment: iainn, no I don't have Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler and any other none standart php classes, except [168] => Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader. All other available classes are php classes.

Comment: delboy1978uk, I removed $loader = , I did not change script behavior.

Comment: @NIck Can you share this enigmatic "script" with us? :)

Comment: At that moment require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
$classes = get_declared_classes();
echo '<pre>';
//print_r($loader);
print_r( $classes );
//print_r( $methods );
echo '</pre>';
I don't see any crawler class available. Only composer classes 
die();

Comment: `get_declared_classes` won't return any classes that haven't yet been autoloaded. Classes are only read from the vendor directory *the first time they're used*. You haven't referenced `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler` anywhere, so it won't be shown.

Comment: @rob006, I have added that script, now I only to get DomCrawler class to work with that. Nothing special and extra serious...

Comment: Nick, mate, have you tried `use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler;` up top, and just doing `new DomCrawler`?

Comment: @iainn , if I understand you correctly I do not need to change anything in composer directory. I can do require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';
$var = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler(); but it returns fatal error that class is not found...

Comment: No, you should never change anything under the vendor directory. Stop trying to guess what Composer is doing and just write your code. *All you need to do* is require the autoloader, and start using the classes.

Comment: @iainn I did that require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php'; $var = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler(); and got Fatal Error that class is not found...

Comment: @NIck That's because there is no such class. This is not Composer fault, you just requesting something that does not exist.

Comment: @Nick, Yes, like a few people have said already, the name of the class is `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler`

Comment: @iainn Yess.... thank you much. There was really a mistake in class name. I corrected it and it seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes will be loaded when you request for them - that is the point of autoloading. If you have have project with thousands of classes and particular request uses only 100 of them, only these 100 classes will be loaded. It allows you to save server resources by skipping loading all of unused classes.

Try to use class before calling `get_declared_classes()` - it should be there.

```
$loader = require '../../composer/vendor/autoload.php';

$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler();

$classes = get_declared_classes();

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $classes );
echo '</pre>';

die();
```